# warning in TextField select material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I'm using material ui in my react project. In part of my code, I have:

```
      <TextField
            id="status"
            select
            label="status"
            value={searchFilters.status}
            onChange={
              (event: any) => {
                event.persist()
                setSearchFilters((oldVal) => {
                  return {
                    ...oldVal,
                    status: event.target.value,
                  }
                })
              }
            }
            fullWidth
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
          >
            <MenuItem value="ACCEPTED">"accept"</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value="REJECTED">"reject"</MenuItem>
      </TextField>
```

but I've got this warning:
`children` must be passed when using the `TextField` component with `select`

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: Where are you seeing this warning?

Comment: In chrome console @Tuhin

Comment: I got no warning but the code does not work. It's just a plain TextField without the Select functionality. I found this feature in the docs, tried to use, did not work. At least got no warnings when properly adding the children like you did.